# flask-sqlalchemy reverse model relation query from child to parent

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have these One To One model define and I'm trying to call the `parent.method1` inside the `child.call_parent_method`

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    child = db.relationship('Child', backref='parent')
    child_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('child.id'),
                                 nullable=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def prop1(self)
        print 'This is method 1'


class Child(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'child'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    def call_parent_method(self):
        self.parent.prop1
```

But what i get is:

```
AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'prop1'
```

Comment: I think you are looking for ```super().prop1()```

Comment: Then he needs child to inherit from the other one right?
class Child(Parent):

Comment: @JoshuaNixon that doesn't apply to sqlalchemy model

Comment: @E.Serra Hi there but my question is not related to python `Class` inheritance but rather a model relationship for flask-sqlalchemy